# UIWebView - Set default date programmatically

Tags: javascript, ios, html, uiwebview

I'm trying to display default date in input embedded in iOS UIWebview :

```
<input type="date" id="startDate" format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

by using this javascript code :

```
var myDate = new Date();
document.getElementById("startDate").value = myDate.getDate()+1.0 + "/" + (myDate.getMonth() * 1.0 + 1.0 * 1.0) + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();
```

The date appears only after I choose a date from the native date picker.
How can I set the default date programmatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in javascript ..

```
    document.getElementById("startDate").valueAsDate = new Date();
```

Comment: I have tried this code and not working for me as well.